# SQL- WHERE and HAVING

Tags: sql, where-clause, having

our task is to replace GROUP BY and HAVING clauses with WHERE, if possible. SQL-Code is as follows:

```
SELECT Sparte , Region , SUM( Umsatz )
FROM Fakten
GROUP BY Sparte , Region
HAVING SUM( Umsatz ) >= 50000
```

Is it possible to change the last two lines using WHERE? If not, why? 
Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: You cannot use `GROUP BY` functions in `WHERE` clause, so no, unless you make an inner query.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is the motivation for wanting this?

Comment: I need this because of the task :D Personally, I do not need this, but well, it is a task.

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari: How does the inner query look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Sparte , Region , SUM(Umsatz) as S_Umsatz
  FROM Fakten
  GROUP BY Sparte , Region
) d
WHERE S_Umsatz >= 50000
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` will filter based on the actual rows
`HAVING` will filter after the `GROUP BY` kicks in

Both have different use cases

**Edit** If you want to use a subquery you can do

```
SELECT Sparte, Region , SUM( Umsatz )
FROM Fakten
WHERE (SELECT SUM( Umsatz ) 
    FROM Fakten as F2 
    WHERE F2.Sparte = Fakten.Sparte
    AND F2.Region = Fakten.Region ) >= 50000
GROUP BY Sparte, Region
```

Or the Matteo way (Much more efficient and elegant)

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but I have been told that replacing GROUP BY and HAVING with WHERE is possible, when using inner queries. How does the query look like ?